# Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

how can be assign chrome extension shortcut to open a popup programmatically not by manually through browser(I want to assign my ctrl+l key to open a chrome extension popup how can we do that)?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the documentation here: [create-link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create). Code is below:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.google.com', active: false});
```

Comment: This will not open a popup, but a new tab.

Comment: how can be press ctrl+m key combo through javascript any idea

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands
through this you can do that. 'menifest.json' file and in background.js file put a code and give your own shortcut key and check it in chrome keyshortcut